# What is a hypermeter?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, meter

I understand both the terms polymeter and polyrhythm, but when songs from bands such as Meshuggah are discussed the term 'hypermeter' keeps popping up. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

Hypermeter is meter at a higher level, combining several measures into one unit. The figure below is taken from an academic analysis of Meshuggah's album "Catch 33" - [link](http://urinieto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/RhythmSeminar-FinalProject-Nieto2013.pdf):

[image]

The cymbal plays a normal 4/4 beat (plus one 2/4 measure), but the snare drum and the bass drum superimpose an additional rhythm, which is indicated by the blue lines, and which can be analyzed as four 7/8 measures. This creates a hypermeter in which those four bars are combined into a larger unit.

Comment: Let's say you have a piece in 3/4 time, made primarily of quarter notes, with 4-measure phrases. Instead of counting the quarters as "one, two, three," you decide to think of them as triplets, so that each 3/4 measure is worth one beat. This is common. Musicians call that "counting in one." Think about this: if you think of each measure as a single beat of triplets, and the piece is made of 4-measure phrases, each phrase is actually behaving at a meta-level as a single measure of 12/8. This is a more straightforward example of hypermeter.

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of academic rhythmic analysis of metal music, I'd suggest looking into the works of Dr. Olivia Lucas: https://www.lsu.edu/cmda/music/people/faculty/lucas.php

I studied under her at Victoria University of Wellington, and can't recommend her work on extreme metal enough.